# How to update Zone File to add A-records

Tags: automation, bind

I need to to automate the addition of a-records to db.mydomain.com.

I've tried to simply edit the file with sed and echo commands, but this doesn't work. It's creating a similarly named file besides it, and copying over all contents instead. No clue why that's happening, it seems more a glitch than purely a security issue.

I've tried to use nsupdate unsuccessfully so far.

```
nsupdate -l
debug
zone db.mydomain.com
update add beta.mydomain.com 30 A my.ip.addy.here
show
send
;; TSIG PSEUDOSECTION:
local-ddns.             0       ANY     TSIG    hmac-sha256. 1888888880 300         32 4                                                                                        UTIabZpqtjLeOxfVT34RJShR52Xi/2U7HSLwKrkAps= 22222 NOERROR 0
```

I check the db.mydomain.com and there is no changes. Am I going about this the correct way? How would I change the a-records from a local script to be run? I need to add, and delete.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Editing the zone file is the way to go - post your structure and we can fix your script. Ofcourse you need to reload bind after editing the files.

Comment: yes, it was the script. getting rather lengthy. I left out a space, finally caught it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

superuser error:

thing= $(cat $otherthing)

should be:

thing=$(cat $otherthing)

I switched other parts around a bit, but this one tripped me up the longest... I need to complete this project before it engulfs me.